# Exportar datos de una datagridview a diversas hojas de excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo para exportar datos a excel y tengo una data gridview que muestra una lista de asistencia de empleados de todos los dias. Lo que deseo hacer y hasta ahora sin solución, es pasar estos datos a diversas hojas de excel por cada empleado. Por ejemplo:

Mi datagridview presenta los campos de la siguiente manera:

```
ID     Nombre     Fecha       Ingreso     Salida
1      Luis       10/08/2021  06:00:00    14:00:00
1      Luis       11/08/2021  06:00:00    14:00:00
1      Luis       12/08/2021  14:00:00    22:00:00
2      Marcos     10/08/2021  06:00:00    14:00:00
2      Marcos     11/08/2021  06:00:00    14:00:00
3      Adrian     10/08/2021  14:00:00    22:00:00
```

Y tengo avanzado la exportanción de estos datos a excel con el siguiente código:

```
public void ExportarExcel(DataGridView lista){
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exportarExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        exportarExcel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);
        int indiceColumna = 0;

        foreach(DataGridViewColumn columna in datalista.Columns)
        {
            indiceColumna++;
            exportarExcel.Cells[1, indiceColumna] = columna.Name;
        }

        int indiceFila = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in datalista.Rows)
        {
            indiceFila++;
            indiceColumna = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn columna in datalista.Columns)
            {
                indiceColumna++;
                exportarExcel.Cells[indiceFila + 1, indiceColumna] = fila.Cells[columna.Name].Value;
            }
        }
        exportarExcel.Visible = true;
}
```

Busque maneras de exportar solos los datos de Luis a una hoja, los datos Marcos a otra hoja y los datos de Adrian a otra hoja con el método `Worksheets`, pero no me funciona. Con este código exporta todos losdatos en una hoja en bruto. Hay una manera para exportar cada dato en diversas hojas?

Comment: Si, se pueden crear hojas programaticamente, es cuestion de buscar la api de Excel, pero deberias poner el codigo que tienes para que alguien pueda responder en base a lo que hiciste

Comment: Si, aplique una referencia a Microsoft Office Excel